# Nasty IE6 <ul> <li> stair bug

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

In that page, the submenu if fine in firefox, but as usual, the nasty explorer is interpreting that differently....

how do you troubleshoot css bug in IE6

what is the css bud there ?

[here is the page](http://www.studioteknik.com/html2/photo-portfolio.php)

---

Sorry to ask, I have found the PERFECT SOLUTION...

[here is the link](http://css-tricks.com/prevent-menu-stepdown/)

here is the text :

```
Here is the remedy:

ul#menu li {
    display: inline; /* Prevents "stepdown" */
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to float the `<li>` elements instead of the links within them

just move the `float: left;` from the links to the `<li>`s

Also remove the float: left; from the `<ul>`