# Stair Stepper Drop Down

Tags: jquery, html, css

We're developing a new site and we added some list drop downs. The client looked at it on his Dell running Windows 7 and IE8. Unfortunately, it's doing an odd stair stepper effect with the lists when they drop down instead of going straight down like they should. I don't know whats going on. Here's the site [Love-Wise](http://www.love-wise.com/).

Thanks :)

Comment: Might I suggest switching your script to Superfish (http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/#examples), it will save you a lot of headaches.

Comment: Please provide the pertinent code.

Answer (score 0):

The menus appear to be `<li>` elements, with `display:block` on them. There are `<br>`s between each one, though, which shouldn't be necessary. Have you tried taking out the `<br>`s between each menu entry, and giving the `<ul>` a fixed width?

Comment: I took over this project from somebody else, so I'm fixing a lot of their code, so I made those changes, unfortunately I'm on a mac so I can't reproduce these, if anyone can tell me if it's working now or not, that would be fantastic.

Comment: you should really look into getting a virtual machine running.  VMware fusion is a great option. With such a large percentage of people using ie still, you need to be able to test in this environment.

Comment: What @jtmkrueger said; it's really a must anymore. And not only for IE, but I have found occasional (though more minor, admittedly) differences between the Mac and PC versions of Safari and Firefox.

Comment: I used to have one, but it died. I'm going to get a new computer soon and triple boot it, ubuntu, windows and mac

Comment: You may wish to buy a license for Windows and run it on your Mac in a VM or with Boot Camp. It's very difficult to debug IE CSS and JS issues without actually testing on each version. Once you have Windows, I recommend using the VHD images MS supplies to test on each version of IE.

Comment: I would suggest to check the page with [w3-validator](http://validator.w3.org/). 99 errors isn't the best base for working out the problem...

Answer (score 0):

[Nasty IE6 <ul> <li> stair bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1707981/nasty-ie6-ul-li-stair-bug)

Answer (score 0):

I haven't actually looked at the website, but the stair bug is a common thing in css, the best way to always avoid these kind of conflicts is to float the anchor  tag inside the

not the li itself, then set the display property of the list item

into inline, although it should be inlined since the items within are floating to the left or right, so basically not vertical
this bug i guess is rendered by Internet Explorer 6, any way that's about it, but in other cases you need to watch out for the hight of the

if that to  is set